# How do I create keys for Kin marketplace JWT integration

Tags: jwt, kin

Hey I want to create an app that uses JWT integration with Kin marketplace. I need to create ES256 signed JWT and provide the keys to Kin ecosystem.

How do I create elliptic curve keys in PEM format?

Answer (score 2):

As described in Kin marketplace server wiki: [Creating ES256 Keys](https://github.com/kinecosystem/marketplace-server/wiki/Creating-ES256-Keys), you can use the `openssl` command line tool to generate keys in pem format.
To create a 256 ECDSA public and private keypair:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout -out kin-es256_0-priv.pem
openssl ec -in kin-es256_0-priv.pem -pubout -out kin-es256_0.pem
```